# How to fix Intermittent Corrupted Display of Text in Console and Elsewhere

Tags: fonts, console, screen-corruption

For unknown reasons, a little while ago my computer began to display slightly corrupted text in the console. The font is just barely able to read, like random bits of the characters got switched around.

Here's the basics:

- Console Text is corrupted
- Font in the title of windows like Google Chrome are corrupted, but nothing in the webpage itself.
- **And Really Weird Part.... If I Highlight the corrupted text, it will *sometimes* display the corrected version of the text!**

[I included a screen shot so you can see what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjgZN.png) As you can see, basically everything is corrupted/unreadable, except the part that I highlighted.

Any ideas? The only thing I can think of is that my RAM is maybe old and is writing slightly corrupted bits of data to the RAM?

**Thank you so much everyone! :)** I really really want to fix this -- it is *super* annoying!!

### **EDIT 1: **

This is a lenovo laptop with integrated graphics. I have started to get the impression that it might be a hardware issue too. Except my suspicioun is that the RAM might have gotten corrupted or something so that bits written to it are not written in EXACTLY the correct order so they display weird. The laptop is a Lenovo T400s with Integrated Graphics (Intel GMA 4500MHD). I really hope its a software fix though!

Regards,
Taylor

Comment: What brand of graphics card are you using (AMD/ATI/Nvidia/Intel)?  What driver are you using for it (proprietary/open)?  Have you tried updating the BIOS/UEFI?  (It probably won't do much for some drivers but may help for  others.)

Comment: @user4901968  The laptop is a Lenovo T400s, so its got integrated graphics (Intel GMA 4500MHD). Also, how would I go about updating the BIOS? And any ideas about a console command that I could use to determine which drivers are being used?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? (14.04, 15.10, etc.)